# Should I export router directly or as an instance of a class in TypeScript NodeJS?

Tags: typescript, express, class, oop, routes

I am making an application with NodeJS, ExpressJS and TypeScript. Main code is in `app.ts` and code for routing is in `routes.ts`.

```
// app.ts

import express from 'express';
import mainRouter from './routes';

class Server {
    private app = express();

    private initMiddlewares () {

    }

    private initRoutes () {
        this.app.use('/', mainRouter.getRouter()); // Is this a good approach?
    }

    start () {
        this.initMiddlewares();
        this.initRoutes();
        this.app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
        })
    }
}
```

```
// routes.ts

import { Router } from 'express';
import v1Router from './v1';

class MainRouter {
    private router = Router();

    constructor () {
        this.router.use('/v1', v1Router.getRouter());
    }

    getRouter () {
        return this.router;
    }
}

const mainRouter = new MainRouter();

export default mainRouter;
```

**My Question:** Should I export router directly without making a class or export instance of class as mentioned in above code?

Answer (score 1):

Export `MainRouter` and call the `getRouter` method

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import v1Router from './v1';

export class MainRouter {
    private router = Router();

    constructor () {
        this.router.use('/v1', v1Router.getRouter());
    }

    getRouter () {
        return this.router;
    }
}
```

In app.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import MainRouter from './routes';

class Server {
    private app = express();

    private initMiddlewares () {

    }

    private initRoutes () {
        this.app.use('/', new MainRouter().getRouter());
    }

    start () {
        this.initMiddlewares();
        this.initRoutes();
        this.app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted to make a single instance of that class throughout the application. That's why I exported the instance. Is it okay to do like that?

Comment: Both are okay but if you want to make changes later in future based on constructor. exporting class approach will be helpful.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the info

Comment: @AbhishekPankar if this answers, consider accepting ans here Thank you